# Angular setInterval error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to set the polling for one page, and disable it when the user quit this page. but i got an error during the build, when i call the function setInterval for the polling:

```
error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
```

Here is the class:

```
export class CommandPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private lastUpdate: number;
  private timer: any;
  private pollingTimer: any;
  private seconds = 0;

  constructor(private router: Router, private consultService: ConsultService, private configService: ConfigService) {

    this.configService.getConfigData('pollingEnabled').subscribe(enabled => {
      if (enabled) {
        let j = 0;
        this.configService.getConfigData('pollingInterval').subscribe(interval => {
          this.pollingTimer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('polling', ++j);
            console.log('polling', interval);
            this.seconds = 0;
            this.consultService.sendConsultPollingRequest();
          }, interval * 1000);
          this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.lastUpdate = interval - this.seconds++;
          }, 1000);
        });
      }else {
        console.log('Polling disabled');
      }
    });
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Will clear when component is destroyed e.g. route is navigated away from
    if (this.pollingTimer) {
      clearInterval(this.pollingTimer);
    }
    if (this.timer) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    console.log('Clear polling');
  }

}
```

Do you have any idea where the proble is? thank you.

Comment: What is the return value of `this.configService.getConfigData('pollingInterval')`? I'm assuming `Observable<string>`, which makes `interval` a `string` and that would explain your error.

Comment: make sure interval variable is number

Comment: which line you are having  this error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is very much clear :

```
this.configService.getConfigData('pollingInterval').subscribe(interval => {
```

You are not getting `interval` value as `number` , coz of that , these two line

```
interval * 1000

this.lastUpdate = interval - this.seconds++;
```

is throwing error of

> error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of
>   type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

Comment: Thank you, i thought the problem is about setInterval return value. ^^

Comment: @pierre , Glad to know that :) , will you please upvote and accept the answer?